# Delete files based on year

Tags: shell, files, rm, timestamps

I need to delete all files in a directory that were created in 2009. What command can I use to do that?

Answer (score 9):

Most filesystems don't store the creation time of a file, so the best you can do is check the last time the file was modified.

If you have a recent version of GNU find (e.g. on Linux or Cygwin) or FreeBSD or OSX, you can directly compare the date of a file with that of another file. In addition, these versions of find can use the file creation time (called its birth time, indicated with a `B`) if it's available on your system. Replace `B` by `m` below to use the modification time rather than the birth time.

```
find /path/to/directory -newerBt '2009-01-01' ! -newerBt '2010-01-01' -type f -delete
```

Run it once without `-delete` first to make sure these are the files you want. The command above will also delete files in subdirectories; if this is not desired, add `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` after the directory name.

If your version of `find` doesn't have the `-newerXY` primary, you'll need to create timestamp files to mark the boundaries of the range of times you want to match.

```
touch -t 200901010000 /tmp/from
touch -t 201001010000 /tmp/to
find /path/to/directory -newer /tmp/from ! -newer /tmp/to -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Zsh's [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) can match files in a time interval, but the boundaries can only be indicated relative to the current date (e.g. *N* days ago).

```
rm /path/to/directory/*(.m+566^m+931)
```

You can also use timestamp files for precise dates, but you lose in terseness.

```
touch -t 200901010000 /tmp/from
touch -t 201001010000 /tmp/to
rm /path/to/directory/*(.e\''[[ $REPLY -nt /tmp/from && $REPLY -ot /tmp/to ]]'\')
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have said `find` but you may also want to check out `tmpwatch`.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command, with the proper options should be able to do exactly what you want.

Since you phrased your question pretty much like a homework assignment, I'm going to leave a thorough read of the manual page as an exercise for the clued; [this tutorial](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/04/atime-ctime-mtime-in-unix-filesystems/) provided by @jfgagne should help quite a bit.

Comment: `'ctime'` is not the creation time of the file, it is the last time the inode structure changed. So it will be updated when file permissions or ownership is changed. See [this tutorial](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/04/atime-ctime-mtime-in-unix-filesystems/) for more info.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Corrected my answer and added your tutorial -- thanks!